# How to build a saturated model for logistic regression in R?

Tags: r, logistic, model-comparison, wald-test

I want to build a saturated model in R for my logistic regression. I already tried the following code obtained from another question posted here ([Logistic Regression : How to obtain a saturated model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114073/logistic-regression-how-to-obtain-a-saturated-model)):

```
y = c(1,1,1,0,0,0)
a <- factor(1:length(y)) 
fit <- glm(y~a,family=binomial) 
summary(fit)
```

But there is an error probably caused by the length of the y variable; it is too long to process in the above code and causes R to crash with the following error displayed "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3.4 Gb".

Is there is any other way to build a saturated logistic regression model?

I want to build the saturated model to compare it latter with my model using a Wald Chi-square test as a goodness of fit test. I already have the Wald Chi-square test for the null versus my model.

Thank you

Comment: Why not use the deviance goodness of fit test?  The deviance for a saturated model is 0 so you don't even have to fit it.

Comment: @DemetriPananos Thank your for your reply. My research boss wants me to report the Wald Chi-square.

Comment: Are you saying that your predictor is a factor variable with a huge number of levels? Then the issue is that dummy encoding results in a truly huge design matrix.

Comment: @Roland The y variable is a 0 or 1 dummy. But the code says a <- factor(1:length(y))  which would result in an extremly long variable because of the length of y observations.

Comment: OK. R needs to add a column of 0/1 values to the design matrix for each observation. The size of the resulting design matrix is n x n. I bet you don't have sufficient memory to create such a large matrix in R. But even if you do have sufficient memory, I'd expect you don't have enough memory for any computations with that matrix.

Comment: @Roland Yes, that's the problem. Thank you.